# Insert Smarty variable in a variable

Tags: php, templates, smarty

i'm trying to insert a string containing various smarty variables and other text ( `test  {$testvar} ...` ) in a smarty variable with this method

```
$this->tpl()->assign('sCurrentView',$test);
```

But smarty does not resolve the content and displays the smary variables as text.

What am i doing wrong? Isn't this working?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315046/smarty-evaluate-a-template-stored-in-a-php-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a minor syntax error to me.

```
$smarty_object->assign('wanted_template_name', $value);
```